# Launch debian 9 installer from live session

Tags: linux, debian, installation, liveusb

I've just burned debian-live-9.4.0-amd64-gnome to a usb pen drive. Then started the live session and now I want to start the installer.

I have to go into the live session because I have to manually install my Broadcom BCM43142 wireless driver. After that I want to start the installer, but I can't figure out how to do it. Tried searching for debian-installer-launcher or similar program but couldn't find anything like that.

Comment: I'd try [these unofficial (but prepared by Debian folks) images containing firmware packages](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/); you probably will need the `firmware-brcm80211` package to get it going.

Comment: See this answer on U&L : https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/314829/153195

Answer (score 0):

To launch the debian installer from the terminal , run:

```
sudo debian-installer-launcher
```

To launch the debian installer in the terminal and keep using the live session , [follow this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314792/debian-live-install-how-to-launch-the-installer-on-the-terminal-without-aborti/314829#314829) by [@Stephen Kitt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/86440/stephen-kitt):

> According to the documentation,
>
> ```
> sudo debian-installer-launcher --text
> ```
>
> will launch the text-mode installer in a new terminal window.

Comment: Doesn't work on Debian 11 (bullseye) live system